# Tortoise SVN crashed on Import. Can I resume? How?

Tags: svn, import, tortoisesvn, resume

I was importing a very large game project to my local system. SVN just froze at 140GB (out of 170). I let it sit for 4 hours hoping it would wake up, but it didn't. I End Tasked tortoise svn and rebooted my system.
Now if I try to Import again it says it already exists. There's no clean-up option as it's not a working directory yet. Is it possible to resume a failed import or do I have to start over?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, someone on the tortoise SVN group pointed out that it doesn't matter if the import fails, I can just checkout what's there and then commit the missing files.